# Changing scene units on completed blender drawing

Tags: blender, measurement

For ease of use, I used cm to create a 3d model of a structure I want to build.  Now that it's completed, and I have to build in RL, I might want to go back to feet and inches, since US real life lumber, tape measures etc use imperial.

My question is: can I change the scene units back to imperial without blowing anything up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the scene tab in the properties section and there you can change the measurement units. I don't think that should mess something up, but just to be safe, make a copy of the .blend file and store it somewhere else for backup

Comment: Please respond if it worked for you, and if it did, please mark this as answer.